# How to make the union between two MKCoordinateRegion

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, mapkit, mkmapview, mkcoordinateregion

I'm trying to do the union between two MKCoordinateRegion. Does anybody have an idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 23):

There is a `MKMapRectUnion` function which accepts two `MKMapRects` so you could first convert each `MKCoordinateRegion` to an `MKMapRect` and then call that function (and convert the result back to an `MKCoordinateRegion` using the `MKCoordinateRegionForMapRect` function).

The conversion method might look like this:

```
- (MKMapRect)mapRectForCoordinateRegion:(MKCoordinateRegion)coordinateRegion
{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D topLeftCoordinate = 
        CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(coordinateRegion.center.latitude 
                + (coordinateRegion.span.latitudeDelta/2.0), 
            coordinateRegion.center.longitude 
                - (coordinateRegion.span.longitudeDelta/2.0));

    MKMapPoint topLeftMapPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(topLeftCoordinate);

    CLLocationCoordinate2D bottomRightCoordinate = 
        CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(coordinateRegion.center.latitude 
                - (coordinateRegion.span.latitudeDelta/2.0), 
            coordinateRegion.center.longitude 
                + (coordinateRegion.span.longitudeDelta/2.0));

    MKMapPoint bottomRightMapPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(bottomRightCoordinate);

    MKMapRect mapRect = MKMapRectMake(topLeftMapPoint.x, 
                            topLeftMapPoint.y, 
                            fabs(bottomRightMapPoint.x-topLeftMapPoint.x), 
                            fabs(bottomRightMapPoint.y-topLeftMapPoint.y));

    return mapRect;
}
```

Then, to actually do the union:

```
MKCoordinateRegion region1 = ...
MKCoordinateRegion region2 = ...

MKMapRect mapRect1 = [self mapRectForCoordinateRegion:region1];
MKMapRect mapRect2 = [self mapRectForCoordinateRegion:region2];

MKMapRect mapRectUnion = MKMapRectUnion(mapRect1, mapRect2);

MKCoordinateRegion regionUnion = MKCoordinateRegionForMapRect(mapRectUnion);
```

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is looking for a swift equivalent using extensions,

```
extension MKCoordinateRegion {
    func mapRectForCoordinateRegion() -> MKMapRect {
        let dLat = span.latitudeDelta / 2.0
        let dLon = span.longitudeDelta / 2.0

        let topLeft = MKMapPointForCoordinate(
            CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(center.latitude + dLat, center.longitude - dLon))
        let botRight = MKMapPointForCoordinate(
            CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(center.latitude - dLat, center.longitude + dLon))

        return MKMapRectMake(
            topLeft.x,
            topLeft.y,
            fabs(botRight.x - topLeft.x),
            fabs(botRight.y - topLeft.y))
    }

    func unionWith(region: MKCoordinateRegion) -> MKCoordinateRegion {
        let union = MKMapRectUnion(
            self.mapRectForCoordinateRegion(),
            region.mapRectForCoordinateRegion())

        return MKCoordinateRegionForMapRect(union)
    }
}
```

And can be used like

```
let region1 = ...
let region2 = ...

let regionUnion = region1.unionWith(region2)
```

Answer (score 0):

i did a little test on both 4.3 and 5.0 and it seems that the conversion is not correct

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"heart.png"] imageByScalingProportionallyToSize:CGSizeMake(100, 100)]];
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100);
imageView.center = [mapView convertCoordinate:mapView.centerCoordinate toPointToView:canvasView];
[canvasView addSubview:imageView];

MKCoordinateRegion region = [mapView convertRect:imageView.frame toRegionFromView:canvasView];
MKMapRect maprect;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i ++)
{
    maprect = [mapView mapRectForCoordinateRegion:region];
    NSLog(@"%f, %f, %f, %f", region.center.latitude, region.center.longitude, region.span.latitudeDelta, region.span.longitudeDelta);
    NSLog(@"%f, %f, %f, %f", maprect.origin.x, maprect.origin.y, maprect.size.width, maprect.size.height);
    region = MKCoordinateRegionForMapRect([mapView mapRectForCoordinateRegion:region]);
}
```

14.718256, -40.078125, 63.837150, 70.312500

78118912.000000, 94811514.406252, 52428800.000000, 52428799.999997

17.416993, -40.078125, 63.837150, 70.312500

78118912.000000, 91803983.982924, 52428800.000000, 53344239.567355

20.649080, -40.078125, 63.837150, 70.312500

78118912.000000, 87976363.978412, 52428800.000000, 54699220.734715

24.548345, -40.078125, 63.837150, 70.312500

78118912.000000, 82962597.189840, 52428800.000000, 56765991.576236

29.305644, -40.078125, 63.837150, 70.312500

78118912.000000, 76093086.024249, 52428800.000000, 60073659.997575