# How to convert CGRect to MapRect

Tags: ios, mkmaprect

I created a method as below to convert a CGRect to MapRect as below

```
- (MKMapRect)mapRectForRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D topleft = [mapView convertPoint:CGPointMake(rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y) toCoordinateFromView:canvasView];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D bottomeright = [mapView convertPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(rect), CGRectGetMaxY(rect)) toCoordinateFromView:canvasView];
    MKMapPoint topleftpoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(topleft);
    MKMapPoint bottomrightpoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(bottomeright);

    return MKMapRectMake(topleftpoint.x, topleftpoint.y, bottomrightpoint.x - topleftpoint.x, bottomrightpoint.y - topleftpoint.y);
}
```

I did a little test.

```
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"heart.png"] imageByScalingProportionallyToSize:CGSizeMake(100, 100)]];
    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100);
    imageView.center = [mapView convertCoordinate:mapView.centerCoordinate toPointToView:canvasView];
    [canvasView addSubview:imageView];

    CGRect rect = imageView.frame;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i ++)
    {
        NSLog(@"%f, %f, %f, %f", rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y, rect.size.width, rect.size.height);
        maprect = [self mapRectForRect:rect];
        NSLog(@"%f, %f, %f, %f", maprect.origin.x, maprect.origin.y, maprect.size.width, maprect.size.height);

        region = MKCoordinateRegionForMapRect(maprect);
        rect = [mapView convertRegion:region toRectToView:canvasView];
    }
```

It works pretty well on iOS 5:

> 110.000000, 180.000000, 100.000000, 100.000000
>
> 78118912.000000, 94811514.406252, 52428800.000000, 52428799.999997
>
> 110.000000, 180.000000, 100.000000, 100.000000
>
> 78118912.000000, 94811514.406252, 52428800.000000, 52428799.999997
>
> 110.000000, 180.000000, 100.000000, 100.000000
>
> 78118912.000000, 94811514.406252, 52428800.000000, 52428799.999997
>
> 110.000000, 180.000000, 100.000000, 100.000000
>
> 78118912.000000, 94811514.406252, 52428800.000000, 52428799.999997
>
> 110.000000, 180.000000, 100.000000, 100.000000
>
> 78118912.000000, 94811514.406252, 52428800.000000, 52428799.999997

But, the result on iOS 4.3 is a little weird.

> 110.000000, 180.000000, 100.000000, 100.000000
>
> 78118912.000000, 94811514.406252, 52428800.000000, 52428799.999997
>
> 110.000000, 174.263596, 100.000000, 101.746048
>
> 78118912.000000, 91803986.406252, 52428800.000000, 53344231.999997
>
> 110.000000, 166.962997, 100.000000, 104.330460
>
> 78118912.000000, 87976370.406253, 52428800.000000, 54699207.999997
>
> 110.000000, 157.400009, 100.000000, 108.272507
>
> 78118912.000000, 82962610.406253, 52428800.000000, 56765975.999997
>
> 110.000000, 144.297470, 100.000000, 114.581375
>
> 78118912.000000, 76093106.406254, 52428800.000000, 60073639.999996

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKOverlayView_class/Reference/Reference.html `- (MKMapRect)mapRectForRect:(CGRect)rect`

Comment: i checked it. it's not what i want. i want to convert a rect in other views to mapview. method on  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6775718/how-to-make-the-union-between-two-mkcoordinateregion does not work correctly either.

Comment: anybody has the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (Swift code) seems  to work fine. In this case, `mapView` is of type `GMSMapView!`, so `mapView.frame` is of type `CGRect`.

```
let mkMapSize = MKMapSize(width: Double(self.mapView.frame.width), height: Double(self.mapView.frame.height))
let mkMapPoint = MKMapPoint(x: Double(self.mapView.frame.origin.x), y: Double(self.mapView.frame.origin.y))
let mkMapRect = MKMapRect(origin: mkMapPoint, size: mkMapSize)
```