# Get all annotations around another annotation

Tags: objective-c, ios, mkannotation, mkmaprect

I'm trying to get all annotations around another annotation on a specified area, but I can't figure how to do it. Now I'm trying with:

```
MKMapRect mapRect = MKMapRectMake(annotation.coordinate.longitude, annotation.coordinate.latitude, 10.0, 10.0);
NSSet *nearbyAnnotations = [map annotationsInMapRect:mapRect];
```

but nearbyAnnotations is empty. I tried by swapping longitude with latitude and also with bigger numbers for the 3rd and 4th parameters, but still no result. How I should do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `MKMapRect` uses `MKMapPoint` units which are *not* the same thing as `CLLocationDegrees`.

The [`MKMapRectMake` function](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MapKitFunctionsReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008209-CH2-SW9) needs the top-left `MKMapPoint` and then the width and height (again in `MKMapPoint` units).

Basically, you need to use the the `MKMapPointForCoordinate` function to help you do this conversion from degrees to `MKMapPoint` units.

First, you could construct an `MKCoordinateRegion` and then convert it to an `MKMapRect`.

For example:

```
//create a region 10km around the annotation...
MKCoordinateRegion mapRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance
                                 (annotation.coordinate, 10000, 10000);

//convert the MKCoordinateRegion to an MKMapRect...
MKMapRect mapRect = [self mapRectForCoordinateRegion:mapRegion];
```

The `mapRectForCoordinateRegion` method is something you have to write.

For an example of one way to write it, see this answer:
[How to make the union between two MKCoordinateRegion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6775718/how-to-make-the-union-between-two-mkcoordinateregion)

By the way, note that in your case, `annotationsInMapRect` will include the annotation that you are searching around (since you are using it as the center).

Comment: There's no problem if it includes the current annotation, I know how to handle this. Thank you a lot